# Turn CLR Exception trapping on and off easily in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: exception, ide, settings, visual-studio-2013

I find myself turning on and off *CLR Exception trapping* in **VS2013** a *lot*.  Usually it's off since a lot of libraries/components throw non-critical Exceptions and debugging would be really onerous with those left on.  But when I get an Exception from some unexpected part of the code, I need to switch it back on to find the location of the original Exception.

Right now I have to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and then click on the checkbox for CLR Exception trapping to turn it on.  And then I need to repeat that right after I've found the root Exception and fixed the problem, but unchecking the option of course.  I know this sounds like a small thing, but doing 20 to 30 to even more times a day, it becomes one of those things I'd like to make as easy as possible.

Is there any way to tweak the IDE to set this up?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you might be interested in my VS extension [Exception Breaker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/50091e25-9e75-40d3-9780-a05892f474de).
It provides a toolbar button to quickly toggle all CLR exceptions on and off.

[image: Toolbar screenshot]